# iOS navigation bar messed up after pressing back while sliding back

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10.2

I was messing up with an app I'm developing and found that when I have three ViewControllers let's say **A -> B -> C** if I start to slide back from **C** to **B** and press the back button while doing so it goes from **C** to **A** and sometimes messes up the navigation bar. I've been able to reproduce this issue in Apple's Music App, here's a picture of what it looks like.

[Music App example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuVG0.png)

I've not been able to reproduce in the few non Apple applications I use. For instance in Whatsapp going from Chats to a particular chat and then displaying the contact information does not enable the back button while sliding back.

So, is there a way to disable the navigation bar while I'm sliding back to avoid this? I'm using Swift 3, iOS 10.2 and XCode 8.2.

Thanks.

Comment: What about disabling the backbutton in viewWillDisAppaer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
//For swift 3
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up swizzling viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear to enable and disable user interaction on the navigation bar.